# Create JSON string from a Map with arrays as entries

Tags: javascript, collections

My data structure object is a Map with the following structure:

```
{
  "2018-09-25":[0,1,2,0,8],
  "2018-10-17":[0,2,0,0,0],
  "2018-10-26":[0,2,1,0,0],
  "2018-10-29":[0,2,2,1,0],
  "2018-10-31":[0,3,2,1,0],
  "2018-11-01":[0,3,3,1,0],
  "2018-11-02":[0,4,4,1,0]
}
```

I use `JSON.stringify` and then `JSON.parse`. However, I would need the elements to be somehow named so that I can reference them (e.g. when drawing a chart).
I tried the following but I get `NaN` as a value.

```
data = Object.keys(data).map(function (k) { 
        return {date: new Date(k), value: +data[k]};
      });
```

I would like to have something like this:

> Key: "2018-09-25"
>       1:0
>       2:1
>       3:2
>    4:0
>   5:8

Comment: It would help if you'd post the *actual* data structure in JavaScript terms, or at least a representative part of it. Also, it would be good to explain *why* you call `JSON.stringify()` and then `JSON.parse()` on the data.

Comment: Please also add the data structure you would like to transform your map to.

Comment: Thanks for adding the desired result, but it's not clear what you want. Why not just post actual javascript?

Comment: Remove the "+" at  "return {date: new Date(k), value: +data[k]};". The correct line is "return {date: new Date(k), value: data[k]};"

Comment: @MarkMeyer Basically I want to draw a chart. But I do not know how to reference individual elements in the arrays. The chart should have 5 lines, for each element.

Comment: Why don't you reference the individual array elements with their index?

Comment: @MarkMeyer So far I was not able to get the Array so I can reference it. But thanks once I get it I believe this will work.

Comment: @TwilightTitus Thanks, this helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `map()` it looks like you want an array as a final result. But, since the array will be a different size, `map()` doesn't really work. You can use reduce to flatten out the inner arrays into one big array:

```js
let o = {"2018-09-25":[0,1,2,0,8],
         "2018-10-17":[0,2,0,0,0],
         "2018-10-26":[0,2,1,0,0],
         "2018-10-29":[0,2,2,1,0],
         "2018-10-31":[0,3,2,1,0],
         "2018-11-01":[0,3,3,1,0],
         "2018-11-02":[0,4,4,1,0]
        }
let newAr = Object.entries(o).reduce((arr, [key, values]) => {
    return arr.concat(values.map(n => ({date: new Date(key), value: n})))
}, [])

console.log(newAr)
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Thanks, yes! It provides the format I was trying to get.

Comment: May I ask, how do I get the length of the array? I tried something like newAr.Value.length but that does not work.

Comment: The length of the final array is just `newAr.length`, is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I mean I should get 5 - there are 5 elements in an array under each key.

Comment: Now that it's flattened out, it's a little work to get the length. The easiest way is to just look at your original object and get the length of the array. In the example above: ` o['2018-09-25'].length`. Otherwise you'll need to filter or reduce the result to regroup the items.